# sql server: why transaction log is not truncated?

Tags: sql-server

With SQL server 2005, 2008 as well in 2012, I often face a problem with transaction log not being truncated after backup of the log. It keeps growing until we run out of disk space.

In this case I use

```
BACKUP LOG <db> TO DISK='NUL'
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE(<TransactionLogName>, 1)
GO
```

which I want to avoid.

The various posts found on the net don't clearly give an answer. Why does this happens? there's no open transaction shown with DBCC OPENTRAN

Is it a bug? Is it related to the log auto-growth?

We cannot switch to a simple model which prevents from recovering and doesn't resolve the problem too.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189085(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: The answers *are* clear and it isn't a bug. You *don't* want to truncate the log unless there's a serious reason. Allocating disk space is expensive and can lead to fragmentation. You *don't* want to pay the IO cost for reallocations when your DB is under heavy usage. It's far cheaper to reuse the existing log pages. That's why truncating the log is a *bad* idea in production databases.

Answer (score 0):

From the article of [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179355(v=sql.105).aspx)

> The transaction log is a wrap-around file. For example, consider a
>   database with one physical log file divided into four virtual log
>   files. When the database is created, the logical log file begins at
>   the start of the physical log file. New log records are added at the
>   end of the logical log and expand toward the end of the physical log.
>   Log truncation frees any virtual logs whose records all appear in
>   front of the minimum recovery log sequence number (MinLSN). The MinLSN
>   is the log sequence number of the oldest log record that is required
>   for a successful database-wide rollback.